# Accessing HTTPS Istio Ingress Gateway from Pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, istio

I have a fairly simple setup in my kubernetes cluster, with two zones:

- Low trust (public facing)
- Medium trust (non public)

Both zones have Istio enabled, with:

- Ingress gateway with SSL enabled. For testing within my local docker desktop, I use port 443 for the public facing, and port 443 for medium trust
- Virtual service
- Destination rule

I am deploying apache HTTPD - acting as a reverse proxy within the low trust. The plan is for the HTTPD to then forward the traffic to istio ingress gateway in the medium trust.
Within the medium trust is a Spring boot application.

So, lets say, user is accessing https://lowtrust.avengers.local/avengers. This request will be serviced by the ingress gateway in the lowtrust, and will end up in the HTTPD, which then forward the request to ingress gateway in mediumtrust.

```
LOWTRUST                      MEDIUMTRUST
| GW--> VS-->HTTPD Pod|======>| GW --> VS -->Java Pod|
```

I have created a github repo to demonstrate this:
https://github.com/alexwibowo/avengersKubernetes

The HTTP proxy configuration is here: https://github.com/alexwibowo/avengersKubernetes/blob/main/httpd/conf/proxy.conf.

The Istio ingress gateway for lowtrust:
https://github.com/alexwibowo/avengersKubernetes/blob/main/kubernetes/avengers/charts/avengers-istio/templates/istio-httpd.yaml

and istio ingress gateway for mediumtrust:
https://github.com/alexwibowo/avengersKubernetes/blob/main/kubernetes/avengers/charts/avengers-istio/templates/istio-app.yaml

As you can see, both gateways have their own certs configured. At the moment, I kind of 'cheat' by modifying my /etc/host file to have the following:

```
127.0.0.1            lowtrust.avengers.local
<CLUSTER_IP_ADDRESS> mediumtrust.avengers.local
```

By doing this, when HTTPD pod making request to 'mediumtrust.avengers.local', it will get directed to the istio ingress gateway (thats my understanding anyway).

I've heard that you can actually set up a mutual TLS for the scenario I've described above. With this approach, I wont need to setup the certificate in my mediumtrust ingress gateway - and just use 'ISTIO_MUTUAL'. I think for this, I will also need to set up a 'proxy' service & virtual service in the lowtrust namespace. The virtual service will then manage the communication between lowtrust & mediumtrust. But I'm not 100% how to do this.

Any help / advice is much appreciated!

Edit 1 (2021/07/01)
I've been reading more about this topic. So another option, is to have Service of type 'ExternalName' within the 'lowtrust' namespace.
Which, if I might use the analogy, will act like a 'proxy' for connecting to the service on the other namespace.
e.g.:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: cr1-avengers-app
  namespace: "lowtrust"
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: "cr1-avengers-app.mediumtrust.svc.cluster.local
  ports:
    - port: 8081
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
```

But by using this, I will effectively bypass the Istio VirtualService, DestinationRule that I've defined on the mediumtrust namespace.

Comment: Hi, do I understand correctly that you are having issues specifically on the path of `HTTPD` -> `medium trust path`? IIUC you want to connect to your `medium-trust` with `https` from your `HTTPD` (that was contacted from `low-trust`). I'd reckon this would require to run the proxypass with SSL: https://serverfault.com/questions/84821/apache-proxypass-with-ssl

Comment: Hi @DawidKruk, I've done that in my proxy conf. Still no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've managed to solve this locally is by having an entry in my windows hostfile.
E.g.:

```
127.0.0.1 lowtrust.avengers.local
10.109.161.243 mediumtrust.avengers.local
```

`10.109.161.243` is the Cluster IP address for my istio-ingressgateway. I got this by running `kubectl get svc -n istio-system` from command line.

```
NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                                                                    AGE
istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   10.109.161.243   localhost     15021:30564/TCP,80:31834/TCP,443:31828/TCP,445:32700/TCP,15012:30459/TCP,15443:30397/TCP   21d
```

I was also missing 'SSLProxyEngine' flag in my reverse proxy configuration. So in the end my VirtualHost configuration looks like below:
E.g.:

```
<VirtualHost *:7000>
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPass          /avengers        https://mediumtrust.avengers.local/avengers
    ProxyPassReverse   /avengers        https://mediumtrust.avengers.local/avengers

    CustomLog "/tmp/access.log" common
    ErrorLog /tmp/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```